# Query, each row was granted a number of times in the second column(sql, oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle10g

given a table with two columns (1 - type of string, another - type of number). i need a query(using commands: join and rownum), in which each row was granted a number of times specified for it in the second column. 
for example:

```
col1    col2
----    ----
apple   4
melon   1
banana  2
```

result:

```
apple
apple
apple
apple
melon
banana
banana
```

Comment: oh dear god. what have they done now

Comment: What SQL engine is this?  MySQL? Sql Server? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server, this is possible by judicious use of a tally table (using `sys.all_columns` in this example, the size of which is the upper limit on the number of rows that can be generated) and calculating partial sums for the index number ranges, something like this:

```
;with Ranges as (
    select
        col1,
        (select coalesce(sum(t2.col2), 0)+1
            from MyTable t2 where t2.col1<t1.col1) as indexStart,
        (select coalesce(sum(t2.col2), 0)
            from MyTable t2 where t2.col1<=t1.col1) as indexEnd
    from
        MyTable t1
)
,TallyTable as (
    select
        row_number() over (order by c.object_id, c.column_id) as number
    from
        sys.all_columns c
)
select
    r.col1
from
    Ranges R, TallyTable T
where
    T.number between r.indexStart and r.indexEnd
```

Though as indicated by the comments on the OP, this is not recommended, and it is quite possible there is a better solution to your business problem.

Comment: Nice. As I learned from another thread, Postgresql has a built in "generate_series" function which could be the TallyTable replacement in the Postgresql version.

Comment: thank mellamokb for answer:) but can you write this query with using commands(join, rownum)? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, using a recursive `CTE` would do the job nicely

- Select every row from `YourTable`, adding a counter to the result set.
- Recurse on given columns until the counter reaches the value in `col2`

**SQL Statement**

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT  col1, cnt = 1
  FROM    YourTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  q.col1, cnt + 1
  FROM    q
          INNER JOIN YourTable yt ON yt.col1 = q.col1
  WHERE   cnt < yt.col2          
)  
SELECT  col1
FROM    q
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**Test script**

```
;WITH YourTable(col1, col2) AS (
  SELECT 'apple', 4
  UNION ALL SELECT 'melon', 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'banana', 2
)
, q AS (
  SELECT  col1, cnt = 1
  FROM    YourTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  q.col1, cnt + 1
  FROM    q
          INNER JOIN YourTable yt ON yt.col1 = q.col1
  WHERE   cnt < yt.col2          
)  
SELECT  col1
FROM    q
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I can't get used to the fact that SQL Server requires a statement termination character in front of a statement...

Answer (score 0):

As you have not given a DBMS I assume PostgreSQL:

```
with test_data (col1, col2) as (
  values ('apple', 4), ('melon', 1), ('banana', 2)
) 
select col1 
from (
  select col1, generate_series(1, col2)
  from test_data
) t
```